# Need Help For Completely Transfer in Ubuntu

Tags: 13.04, windows, wine, photoshop

I use ubuntu 13.04 in dual boot with windows. I want to completely move into ubuntu. But I need some help.

I am a freelance web designer. Sometimes my clients send me PSD files to make theme html or anything else. But I can't use photoshop in ubuntu. I know by using wine I can install photoshop. But I have dought that can I slice my psd layers in ubuntu as I do in windows. Sometimes I have to create banner/button in photoshop. So I need a best solution for handling this type of problem.

I hate windows so much. At the first when I used ubuntu 10.04 I am in love in ubuntu. So please help me to move in ubuntu.

Regards,
Mahbub Alam

Comment: You will have to look at alternates to Photoshop, GIMP or inkscape or similar. alternately consider running photoshop in a virtual machine such as KVM or virtualbox.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/).

> GIMP is an advanced picture editor. You can use it to edit, enhance,
> and retouch photos and scans, create drawings, and make your own
> images. It has a large collection of professional-level editing tools
> and filters, similar to the ones you might find in Photoshop. Numerous
> fine-control settings and features like layers, paths, masks, and
> scripting give you total control over your images.
>
> Many image file formats are supported, including JPEG, Photoshop
> (.psd), and Paint Shop Pro (.psp) files. It can also be used to scan
> and print photos.

To install click [**Gimp** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gimp/)

<sup>Source:Ubuntu Apps</sup>